# Calculating $\vec{A}$ in $\vec{B} = \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let's say I have the following relation

$$\vec{B} = \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A}$$

in which I know $\vec{B}$. How can I determine $\vec{A}$ knowing both vector fields and its derivatives are continous in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1):

Well you cannot determine $A$ uniquely because it is not unique: notice that if you add $\nabla\phi$ to any solution you get another. The way to proceed is to use the fact that $$\nabla\times(\nabla\times A)=-\Delta A+\nabla(\nabla\cdot A).$$ By substituting $\nabla\times A=B$, inverting the Laplacian (see comments), and letting $\phi=\Delta^{-1}\nabla\cdot A$, we arrive at $$A=-\frac1\Delta\nabla\times B+\nabla\phi$$ for some scalar function $\phi$. This is essentially known as the Biot-Savart operator. This is used frequently in fields like electromagnetism and fluid mechanics and commonly written as an integral operator (basically using the Newton potential to invert the Laplacian), see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law).

Comment: How are you defining the operator $\frac1{\Delta}$?  And it is not at all clear that by "rearranging" your first centered expression, one would obtain the second.

Comment: @MarkViola Ok, I made it more specific. How one defines this operator should depend on what kind of domain we’re on, what kinds of techniques the poster is familiar with, etc. For example I mentioned the Newton potential. One can also interpret it as a Fourier multiplier, or as the solution to the Poisson equation $\Delta u=f$. (Note it is applied to a field with zero average.)